# Find the counts for all cities

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table [Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c736c2ca03f4458b7c7144663f806a7e)

```
+------+------+------+---------+
| id_a | id_b | City | result  |
+------+------+------+---------+
| 101  | 101  | NY   | Ready   |
| 102  | 102  | TN   | Sold    |
| 103  |      | TN   | Missing |
| 104  | 104  | NY   | Ready   |
|      | 105  | NY   | Missing |
| 106  | 106  | TN   | Ready   |
| 107  | 107  | TN   | Sold    |
+------+------+------+---------+
```

I need a output like

```
+------+-----+----------+---------+------------+
| City | CNT | No_Ready | No_sold | No_Missing |
+------+-----+----------+---------+------------+
| NY   | 3   | 2        | 0       | 1          |
| TN   | 4   | 1        | 2       | 1          |
+------+-----+----------+---------+------------+
```

Logic is just counting the each result for each city. Now i'm getting the result with below query

```
select 'NY' as City,sum(case when city='NY' then 1 else 0 end) as CNT,
            sum(case when city='NY' and result='Ready' then 1 else 0 end) as No_Ready,
            sum(case when city='NY' and result='Sold' then 1 else 0 end) as No_sold,
            sum(case when city='NY' and result='Missing' then 1 else 0 end) as No_Missing
from source
union all
select 'TN' as City,sum(case when city='TN' then 1 else 0 end) as CNT,
            sum(case when city='TN' and result='Ready' then 1 else 0 end) as No_Ready,
            sum(case when city='TN' and result='Sold' then 1 else 0 end) as No_sold,
            sum(case when city='TN' and result='Missing' then 1 else 0 end) as No_Missing
from source
```

But the problem is if city gets added , I have to again write one more `UNION ALL`. Is there anyway i can do this for all the city available in `CITY` column without adding union all for each city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select city,
COUNT(*) as CNT,
            sum(case when result='Ready' then 1 else 0 end) as No_Ready,
            sum(case when result='Sold' then 1 else 0 end) as No_sold,
            sum(case when  result='Missing' then 1 else 0 end) as No_Missing
FROM source
group by city
```

Answer (score 0):

A fast approach would be trying subqueries:

```
select City,
count(*) as CNT,
(select count(*) from Sample where Sample.City = s.City and result = 'Ready') as No_Ready,
(select count(*) from Sample where Sample.City = s.City and result = 'Sold') as No_Sold,
(select count(*) from Sample where Sample.City = s.City and result = 'Missing') as No_Missing,
from Sample s
group by City
```

Note: holder query performance could be better than this one